# Modal Dialog of different widths are not applied with :host and :ng-deep

Tags: css, angular

I have a component in angular which opens up modal dialog on click of the button. I have many such different buttons which open modal dialogs of different types of different width. I am using Ng bootstrap modal dialog and modal dialog all are same width but I want it to be different widths. I try overriding the css in the modal-dialog component ::ng-deep works but :host does not work. What am I doing wrong here, Please suggest.

My css for one of the modal-dialog is as below which works

```
  ::ng-deep .modal-dialog {
    min-width: 700px !important;
    max-width: 900px !important;
    width: 95% !important;
    background-color: red !important;
  }
```

The below css does not get applied

```
:host::ng-deep .modal-dialog {
    min-width: 700px !important;
    max-width: 900px !important;
    width: 95% !important;
    background-color: red !important;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this answer is long overdue, but I just happened to face the same problem and found out the reason.

The "**:host**" pseudo-selector has the CSS rule **applied to the <app-root>** component.

However, your **Dialog is created in a <div> at the same level with <app-root>**, instead of inside the <app-root> component, thus the CSS rule is not applied to it.

Sorry for being so rough, I'm on the clock right now. If you need a more expansive answer, please just leave a comment.

Hope this answer can help someone in the future.

Comment: Needs to be accepted answer.